# How can I make that when I run my application thorugh the VS it will prompt for admin rights?

Tags: c#

I can do it in the application `Debug/Bin` directory to change the exe file of my application property to `Run As Admin`.

But I want it to run as admin also when I'm running it through Visual Studio.

So I created a manifest file which I put it in the `debug/bin` directory of my application and I also have there `mt.exe`

My manifest file content:

```
Executable: hardwareMonitoring.exe 
Manifest:Hardwaremonitoring.exe.manifest
Sample application manifest file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0"
     processorArchitecture="X86"
     name="IsUserAdmin"
     type="win32"/> 
  <description>Description of your application</description> 
  <!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="requireAdministrator"
          uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Now I think I need to use the `mt.exe` somehow or need to add/embed the manifest into my project? The idea is that not it will create automatic on my hard disk in `Debug/Bin` a exe file which is already in `Admin Rights (Run As Admin)` but I want it to prompt for admin right confirmation when I'm running the application in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Have you tried [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3116788/869912)?

Answer (score 2):

When you debug an application (say hello.exe) it is usually run through a proxy application called vshost.exe. That application has the same privileges as the instance of VS you are using.

You can try launching Visual Studio with administrative privileges so vshost.exe and your application is launched with that privileges too.

Comment: Its worth noting `vshost.exe` makes it so debugging is possible

Comment: I need that when i make rebuild solution it will create a new exe file with admin rights so the user wont be able ot change it in properties of the exe file. Thep roblem is that in my program i have something that update every n seconds and if you dont start it as admin it will be null.

Comment: In that case you can try the following:

1. Add a manifest file to the project (Project | Add New Item | General Category | Application Manifest File).
2. Configure the created manifest with the required execution level (as you have already done)
3. Specify the manifest as an application resource. Right click your project and select Properties. On the Application property page locate the "Icon and manifest" section and pick your manifest file from the drop down list.

This way, everytime you rebuild the project, VS will embed the manifest automatically on the executable program.

Answer (score 0):

I had it somewhere i kept it on a text file:

First you create a text file with notepad and add to it:

```
Executable: hardwareMonitoring.exe 
Manifest:Hardwaremonitoring.exe.manifest
Sample application manifest file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0"
     processorArchitecture="X86"
     name="IsUserAdmin"
     type="win32"/> 
  <description>Description of your application</description> 
  <!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="requireAdministrator"
          uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Then you save the file name as: appName.exe.manifest
Then you click on the windows Start>Cmd type in the dos window:

```
mt -manifest appName.exe.manife
st.txt -outputresource:appName.exe;#1
```

If mt.exe is not the application: Debug/Bin directory just give the directory/ies before the mt.

Thats it.

Comment: I did on my visual studio 2010 pro properties>compatiblity marked the checkbox near run as adminisitrator apply and thats it.

Comment: Now i left with one problem is to use the mt.exe or to add for ever the manifest file to my project and make that each time i make Rebuild Solution it will make automatic the application exe file on hard disk under admins rights. Now each time im doing rebuild solution i need on my hard disk to make CMD window of dos and use the mt.exe to make the exe under admin rights.