# Debug visual C++ application as administrator in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am developing an application which needs to save some settings to the registry. I am getting Error 5 when I try to open the key using `RegCreateKeyEx` with `KEY_WRITE` permissions. I use this approach so that the key is created if it does not exist. However when I run the same program with 'Run as Administrator' manually from the Debug folder it works fine.

Is there any way to run the application as administrator when debugging it through Visual Studio? I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: In the project Properties->Linker->Manifest, tell UAC to request Administrator permissions.

Comment: Have you tried running VS2012 as administrator then launching the application through the debugger?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to run Visual Studio elevated (i.e., with Administrator privileges).  If you do this, then by default any processes started by it with the debugger attached will also run elevated.

(Visual Studio *must* be elevated in order to attach to an elevated process, for obvious security reasons.)

Comment: Thanks, was obvious with hindsight! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole nasty "manifest" system you can use to ensure your program always goes to launch as administrator (basically, ensuring that you get that annoying pop up). It is yet another hideous MS abortion, but it is the one way I know of to ensure your program will always run with the permissions needed if it is to run at all- even when being debugged or when invoked from some other program in a released product.

Just search on "microsoft application manifest" or "create application manifest for windows program". See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22092301/505893).